# Unable to install sass using Gem from terminal on Windows

Tags: angularjs, sass, rubygems

I am trying to develop a Web Application using Angular JS. I am about to develop Admin Panel. I will use this template - http://startangular.com/product/flatlogic-angular-material-dashboard/. I need to set up the that admin panel following this instruction - https://github.com/flatlogic/angular-material-dashboard/blob/master/README.md. As you can see, I need to run this command in terminal.

```
$ gem install sass
```

I am using Windows 10. All the steps working fine. But when I run that command, it is giving me this error.

[image]

What is that error and how can I solve it? Is there a way to solve that step without using that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This question saved me.

[Error: SASS installation for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278966/error-sass-installation-for-windows)

I run this command

```
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Before running this

```
gem install sass
```

> This is additional

If you still getting errors, try this.

```
gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
gem update --system
gem sources --remove http://rubygems.org
gem sources --add https://rubygems.org
```